# Cannot make a query with data imported from a csv file

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working with MongoDB version 3.2.11  on Debian 9 32 bits and I have a database with a collection that has data imported from a csv file.

I import data using mongoimport command. The result after using this command is correct. Here is an example:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bccde3ed7ce96087d5e696b"), "month" : "Jan 2000,\"20\",\"The Foo Fighters\",\"Learn To Fly\",\"1883.219\",\"19\",\"-\",\"-\",\"-\",\"-\",\"48\"" }

I try to make the following query and the result is anything displayed (no results and no errors):

```
db.canciones.find({artist:"Foo 
Fighters"});
```

I also try the folowing query:

```
db.canciones.find({artist:"Foo Fighters\"});
```

The result of this query is the error:

E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: unterminated string literal @(shell):1:26

How can I display results of a query?

Thanks

Comment: doesn't look like your data is imported properly, there's only two fields: `_id` and `month` with everything in the latter as a csv string

Comment: Can you paste your csv file here.